# Can't install ecapture

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

IDK what to do, tried with python3.8.5, python3.7,python3.6
It can't install ecapture module

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-fnpxi2jh/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.11.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does `pip install numpy` work?

Comment: @VasilySobolev Where are you installing it from? From an virtual environment? Or from the PATH? Change the directory to Python path and then `python -m pip install ecapture`

Comment: @Jimit Vaghela Just typed in terminal ```pip3 install ecapture```

Comment: You need to understand that typing in the terminal just wont work like that unless your pip and python is installed in PATH variables.

Comment: @Jan  Willems Yeap

Comment: @Jimit Vaghela Other package are installed normal

Comment: Is wheel installed?  `pip3 install wheel`?  And is scikit-build installed?  `pip install scikit-build`?

Comment: Yeas, it is....

Answer (score 3):

Anything before `pip` will result in an error. You just need to download the old version of the `ecapture` to solve your issue.

You can use the command below for windows:

```
pip install ecapture==0.0.7
```

it will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I did this on Google Colab jupyter and it worked.

```
!pip install ecapture
```