# Can't install ecapture on Python3.9 -- Fails building wheels for scikit-image

Tags: python-3.x, macos, scikit-image, python-wheel, pep517

I am using the latest version of Python3, and trying to install through the IntelliJ Terminal.

I have tried creating different env's, I updated all the possible packages: pip, wheel, scipy, numpy, setuptools, and even downloaded scikit-image separately. I also tried using the Mac Terminal, also the same error.

everytime I run the install command:

```
pip install ecapture
```

it shows me this error:

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  Partial import of skimage during the build process.
  error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/private/var/folders/lg/tmt9k7b1587_ppzl3xgptzx80000gn/T/pip-build-env-42dpn7e5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/irina/venv/python3/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c skimage/_shared/geometry.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/skimage/_shared/geometry.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/skimage/_shared/geometry.o.d" failed with exit status 1


----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image
Failed to build scikit-image
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I have also rummaged around and tried to use --no-binary:

```
pip install ecapture --no-binary :all:
```

But again, it gives me the same error of not being able to build the wheels (expect this time, for cmake. Which I also downloaded, to no avail. )

I have been stuck on this for so long I am honestly considering throwing my laptop out of the nearest window.

Comment: Try pip install ecapture=0.0.7 Saw this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447382/cant-install-ecapture